# Time Complexity DFA construction from regex directly

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, runtime, time-complexity, dfa

I wanted to know the time complexity of DFA construction from regular expression directly using algo 3.36 in dragon book .

I was confused regarding how many times outer while loop would execute ? As in Dstates as referred in algo ,will they be equal to number of operands in regex ?

Also how much work will be done in inside **for** loop which executes equal to |Σ| times ?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a terribly constructed question for SO, bye

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times

Comment: @nhahtdh the given complexity is by using NFA for the construction which will results in 2^n states in worst case , hence O(2^n) . i have asked for construction from regex directly

Comment: @gwillie simply put i want to know time complexity of constructing dfa directly from regex using algo 3.36 in Dragon book :|

Comment: @nhahtdh It is not necessary to go through NFA as we can construct a syntax tree from regex and hence use it..... fir more info i recommend you to go through algo 3.36 in dragon book.... i know that its worst case complexity would be 2^n but wanted to know exact expression..

Comment: @gwillie i don't think you have the answer to it now ... 
:/

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the construction would still be O(2<sup>n</sup>). Consider the worst case example as described [in this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/130/what-are-the-conditions-for-a-nfa-for-its-equivalent-dfa-to-be-maximal-in-size/131#131):

> L = {w ∈ {0,1}*: |w| ≥ n and the n-th symbol from the last symbol is 1}

The regular expression corresponding to the language is (0+1)*1(0+1)...(0+1), where the trailing part repeats for n - 1 times. The time complexity would still be O(2<sup>n</sup>), since the number of states in the DFA constructed is O(2<sup>n</sup>) (corresponding to the number of suffixes of a word in L).

Comment: yes, i agree its 2^n in worst case but as i mentioned i wanted to know is there any relation between Dstates mentioned in algo and operators in   regex ... also i asked how much work would be done in for loop

Comment: @Shubham: Regardless of the works done elsewhere, as long as the final result requires the construction of the whole DFA, the overall complexity would be O(2^n). My answer is incomplete, since it doesn't really answer your other questions, though.